# Windows Service Bus - The entity path/name '[some-long-name]' exceeds the '50' character limit

Tags: c#, character, limit

At work we have a Windows Service Bus. Trying to create a message subscription, I get this error message:

```
Windows Service Bus - The entity path/name '[some-long-name]' exceeds the '50' character limit.
```

`ArgumentOutOfRangeException` happening at:

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CheckValidEntityName(String entityName, Int32 maxEntityNameLength, Boolean allowSeparator, String paramName) +352
```

I supposed there's a way to change this limitation, but I have no idea how. Thank you if you can help.